# Laravel 5.3の多言語化について

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, localization, i18n

バリデーションメッセージを多言語化(今回は日本語化)する場合、

`/resources/lang/ja/validation.php`

上記ファイルのattributes配列に`フィールド名 => 日本語名`で記述すれば
フィールド名が日本語化されますが、
異なるモデルで同じフィールド名を使用している場合はどうやって分ければいいのでしょうか？

例えば、
Userモデルには`ユーザ名`という意味のnameフィールドがあり、
Shopモデルには`店舗名`という意味のnameフィールドがある、といった状況です。

Answer (score 1):

`ValidatesRequests::validate`の場合の属性名指定は

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ], null, [
            'name' => 'ユーザ名',
        ]);
    }
}
```

のようにも指定できますね。

Answer (score 0):

各々でバリデーターを作成すれば可能です。

```
class UsersController extends Controller{

    public function post() {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $validator->setAttributeNames([
            'name' => 'ユーザ名',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('users/')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ShopsController extends Controller{

    public function post() {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $validator->setAttributeNames([
            'name' => '店舗名',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('shops/')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

また、Requestを作成してバリデーションを行なっている場合は
`attributes()`メソッドを用いることができます。

```
class UsersRequest extends FormRequest{

    //...

    public function attributes(){
        return [
            'name' => 'ユーザ名',
        ];
    }
}
```